# No screen shown as connected when using xrandr, not even the one i'm using

Tags: xrandr, monitors

Here is the output of xrandr :

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
  2560x1440 (0x1c2) 596.810MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2591 end 2623 total 2686 skew    0 clock 222.19KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1503 end 1511 total 1543           clock 144.00Hz
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x22e) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
```

As you can see, no screen is shown as connected even though I'm currently using one, HDMI-2. This means that i can't change the resolution and I suspect this is the reason why I'm unable to launch any full screen game or application. My kernel is 5.19.9-arch1-1, I'm using nvidia-dkms 515.65.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.